# CreateService fails 0x6f7 The stub received bad data

Tags: c++

CreateService WINAPI (tasked with creating a Kernel Driver or Windows Service) will randomly fail on some hardware with the error 1783 (0x6F7): The stub received bad data.

From the error definition RPC_X_BAD_STUB_DATA looks like this could be related to a Remote Procedure Call that may be happening on the internal side of things.

Nowhere on the internet have I found any cause / solution for this error.

What could possibly cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the reason for **CreateService**'s LastError being **RPC_X_BAD_STUB_DATA**, **RPC_S_CALL_FAILED**, **RPC_S_CALL_FAILED_DNE** and even sometimes **ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED** is because the windows firewall has blocked a Remote Procedure Call. Simply whitelisting the app or disabling the firewall fixes the issue.

Comment: On a side note: This can also happen when you have too much windows services installed.
It's interesting how the Windows Firewall can affect WinApi's such as CreateService, or in general, anything that can end up in a RPC.